# How to get last inserted IDS of multiple insert in Knex.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, query-builder, knex.js

I need to get all last inserted IDS while inserting multiple records at a time but right now I'm getting only one ID.

```
const data = await querybuilder('surveyresponse').insert(varList)
```

Output:

```
[183]
```

Expected Output:

```
[183,184,185]
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL itself doesnt return that information, so Knex.js don't to it neither. From docs:

```
// Returns [2] in "mysql", "sqlite"; [2, 3] in "postgresql"
knex.insert([{title: 'Great Gatsby'}, {title: 'Fahrenheit 451'}], ['id']).into('books')
```

You could use multiples queries (not the most efficient way):

```
const data = await Promise.all(varList.map(item => querybuilder('surveyresponse').insert(item)
))
```

Other posts mention `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last one so you can get the interval, but this is very risky and error-prone in high concurrency.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` has no concurrency risk.  *["The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients ... each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)*